# Multi-Line Records right way to handle

Tags: spring-batch

Currently I follow [spring-batch docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#multiLineRecords) on how to handle with Multi-Line Records situation

Currently if all line in the same format I can use `FlatFileItemReader` and `FlatFileItemWriter` to write and read csv.

Something like this

```java
@Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<AdaptNeko> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<AdaptNeko>()
                .name("itemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource(INPUT_FILE))
                .delimited()
                .names(new String[]{"name", "age", "potentialLevel"})
                .fieldSetMapper(fieldSet -> NormalNeko.builder()
                        .name(fieldSet.readString("name"))
                        .age(fieldSet.readInt("age"))
                        .potentialLevel(fieldSet.readInt("potentialLevel"))
                        .build())
                .build();
    }
```

Currently the format file is a bit different.

My current csv format:

```
START, day, play
123, 456, 899, abc, xyz
END
START, day1, play23
789, 456, 899, koq, koq
END
```

After doing some research I found out that currently spring-batch have docs about this case but I'm very new with spring-batch so barely understand it. And the second line which is data only don't have start attribute with default value.

In documents example it uses `orderFileTokenizer()` then after that fieldSetMapper back into just one class like `FlatFileItemReader` usage

```java
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader flatFileItemReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Trade> reader = new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<>()
            .name("flatFileItemReader")
            .resource(new ClassPathResource("data/iosample/input/multiLine.txt"))
            .lineTokenizer(orderFileTokenizer())
            .fieldSetMapper(orderFieldSetMapper())
            .build();
    return reader;
}
```

and

```java
@Bean
public PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer orderFileTokenizer() {
    PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer tokenizer =
            new PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer();

    Map<String, LineTokenizer> tokenizers = new HashMap<>(4);

    tokenizers.put("HEA*", headerRecordTokenizer());
    tokenizers.put("FOT*", footerRecordTokenizer());
    tokenizers.put("NCU*", customerLineTokenizer());
    tokenizers.put("BAD*", billingAddressLineTokenizer());

    tokenizer.setTokenizers(tokenizers);

    return tokenizer;
}
```

So may I ask what is this function tokenizer meaning like `headerRecordTokenizer()` and mapping with `Hashmap<>(4)` here means 4 lines each times reading the file?

I don't have the default value in like `FOT*`, `NCU*` like the example so how do I set to the spring-batch know that I want to stop at `END` to begin a new reading?

I'm quite new to spirng-batch so I have bit confused right here because as the document write I see no difference to how `FlatFileItemReader` work when all attributes in one line is stable as my first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So may I ask what is this function tokenizer meaning like headerRecordTokenizer() and mapping with Hashmap<>(4) here means 4 lines each times reading the file?

A logical record in the input file of the example you shared spans 4 physical lines, where each line has to be tokenized differently. This is where the composite line tokenizer comes to play: it will delegate line tokenization to 4 delegate pattern-matching tokenizers, one for each line format.

There is another example which is similar to your requirement, which you can find here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-samples/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/iosample/internal/MultiLineTradeItemReader.java

This one reads items between "BEGIN" and "END", similar to what you have. The complete example can be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples#multiline